# in Emacs mail-mode, how to kill buffer on send?

Tags: emacs

In Emacs, how do I direct to direct mail-mode to kill the buffer after I C-c C-c to send the message? As it is now, it closes the buffer, but the buffer is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Upon successful sending of a message, functions in `mail-send-actions` are called.

`mail-send-actions` is a local variable that is initialized whenever you enter into `mail-mode`, so this might do what you want:

```
(add-hook 'mail-setup-hook
      (lambda ()
        (add-hook 'mail-send-actions 'kill-this-buffer)))
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't work, the buffer is still there after I call C-c C-c mail-send-and-exit.

Comment: See edit.  Unfortunately I have no mail servers available to me in order to test the code.